# Build not showing in testflight after processing?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I have uploaded many builds from yesterday. Build appears faded with processing state in Activity tab but after sometime the build disappears. 
I am unable to find the issue. When i try to upload with same build no. Xcode gives redundant build error which suggest that build is somewhere on testflight but not showing.
Someone suggested it could be certificate issue so i created a new certificate and profile but still facing issues.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem on the email account being used for uploading build.
Problem was i need to add description of Bluetooth usage (NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription) as new requirement for privacy policy.